# Jenkins Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built - triggering job B, then job triggered A again and so on

Tags: maven, jenkins

So i have multiple maven dependency projects but there are only 2 maven jobs A and B which triggers one another in infinite loop!

When A is built it is triggering job B. 
When job B is finished , job A is triggered and so on in infinite loop!

Any ideas?
Both jobs have "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built" checked. (Should be that way.)

No other jobs is triggered except jobB:

Not triggering jobC it has dependencies in the downstream project list
Not triggering jobD because it has dependencies in the downstream project list
Not triggering jobE because it has dependencies in the downstream project list
Triggering a new build of ***jobB***

Why this is happening?

Brgds,
S.

Comment: Why not having a single multi module build? Cause it looks like those projects are dependent on each other...

Comment: We have single parent pom xml (bom) which builds everything, but also we have single jobs which are dependent on each other.